# While 'CASE WHEN' update, other columns become null

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, case-when

I was using user defined table type in tmy database to update several columns via datatable.

So, I wrote following stored procedure and it's working good. But while updating the respective columns, this make all other columns are null.

**My STORED PROCUDURE:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateAbcdItemsByVendorPrice]
      @tblItemUpdate AbcdItemsUpdate READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    MERGE INTO AbcdItems abcdTable
    USING @tblItemUpdate tempTable
    ON abcdTable.ItemPartNumber = tempTable.ItemPartNumber
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        abcdTable.InpostPrice = CASE WHEN tempTable.VendorName = 'Inpost' THEN tempTable.Price END,
        abcdTable.InpostUpdatedDate = CASE WHEN tempTable.VendorName = 'Inpost' THEN GETUTCDATE() END,
        abcdTable.InpostAbsoluteItem = CASE WHEN tempTable.VendorName = 'Inpost' THEN 0 END,

        abcdTable.HRCPrice = CASE WHEN tempTable.VendorName = 'HRC' THEN tempTable.Price END,
        abcdTable.HRCUpdatedDate = CASE WHEN tempTable.VendorName = 'HRC' THEN GETUTCDATE() END,
        abcdTable.HRCAbsoluteItem = CASE WHEN tempTable.VendorName = 'HRC' THEN 0 END,

        abcdTable.AnnecyPrice = CASE WHEN tempTable.VendorName = 'Annecy' THEN tempTable.Price END,
        abcdTable.AnnecyUpdatedDate = CASE WHEN tempTable.VendorName = 'Annecy' THEN GETUTCDATE() END,
        abcdTable.AnnecyAbsoluteItem = CASE WHEN tempTable.VendorName = 'Annecy' THEN 0 END,

        abcdTable.SydneyPrice = CASE WHEN tempTable.VendorName = 'Sydney' THEN tempTable.Price END,
        abcdTable.SydneyUpdatedDate = CASE WHEN tempTable.VendorName = 'Sydney' THEN GETUTCDATE() END,
        abcdTable.SydneyAbsoluteItem = CASE WHEN tempTable.VendorName = 'Sydney' THEN 0 END;
END
```

My table before executing this query for 'Inpost':

```
InpostPrice    HRCPrice    ...
0              0           ...
```

My table after executing this query for 'Inpost':

```
InpostPrice    HRCPrice    ...
213.57         NULL        ...
```

Why HRCPrice is become null? Sorry for the bad English. Help me in this!

Comment: `CASE WHEN tempTable.VendorName = 'HRC' THEN 0 END` is 0 if vendorname equals HRC and null otherwise. if you want to keep the original value otherwise write: `CASE WHEN tempTable.VendorName = 'HRC' THEN 0 ELSE abcdTable.HRCAbsoluteItem END`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning `NULL` because you have no `ELSE` in your `CASE`. I assume that you instead want to use the old value:

```
UPDATE SET
    abcdTable.InpostPrice = CASE WHEN tempTable.VendorName = 'Inpost'
                             THEN tempTable.Price 
                             ELSE abcdTable.InpostPrice END,
   .....
```

From [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

> ELSE else_result_expression: Is the expression returned if no comparison operation evaluates to TRUE. **If this argument is omitted
>   and no comparison operation evaluates to TRUE, CASE returns NULL**

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `else` part in `case` statement.

```
UPDATE SET
        abcdTable.InpostPrice = CASE WHEN tempTable.VendorName = 'Inpost' THEN tempTable.Price 
                                ELSE abcdTable.InpostPrice  END,
        abcdTable.InpostUpdatedDate = CASE WHEN tempTable.VendorName = 'Inpost' THEN GETUTCDATE() 
                                      ELSE abcdTable.InpostUpdatedDate END,
        abcdTable.InpostAbsoluteItem = CASE WHEN tempTable.VendorName = 'Inpost' THEN 0 
                                       ELSE abcdTable.InpostAbsoluteItem END,
......
```

Answer (score 1):

Because each column updated unconditionally and your case statement will default to null.  Put the current value in as the default:

```
     abcdTable.InpostPrice = CASE WHEN tempTable.VendorName = 'Inpost' THEN tempTable.Price 
else abcdTable.InpostPrice
END,
```